# Search for object on Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to search for an object by a property with this code :

```
                ref.orderByChild("aFieldNameOnTheFirebaseCollection").equalTo(mySearchArgument).limitToFirst(1).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                console.log("Yes the object with the key exists !");
                var thisVerificationVarisSetToTrueIndicatingThatTheObjectExists = true ;
            });
```

This works ok if the one or more objects are found on the collection. But, I need to know if no objects exists. I could set the verification var to false before the verification but the verification process is async and I need wait until it is finished. Shoul I use a promise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `child_added` event will fire if (and only if) a child is added. So you cannot use it to detect whether a matching child exists.

Use a `value` event for that:

```
var query = ref.orderByChild("aFieldNameOnTheFirebaseCollection").equalTo(mySearchArgument).limitToFirst(1);
query.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
    console.log("Yes the object with the key exists !");
    var thisVerificationVarisSetToTrueIndicatingThatTheObjectExists = true ;
  }
})
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much !